# Ttk.Treeview cell editing

Tags: python, treeview

So im stuck with my code for a while now. I've also tried to get some help from GPT3 but no help.
So I'm trying to make it so that I could edit specific cells in my `treeview`. I'm going to give the code which part I've identified the fault but as to what's wrong I just cant figure out.

```
def edit_cell(event):
    # Get the selected item (row)
    selected_item = event.widget.focus()

    # Get the column index of the selected cell
    column = event.widget.identify_column(event.x)
    column_index = int(column[1:]) - 1

    # Enable editing for the selected cell
    event.widget.selection_set(selected_item)
    event.widget.focus(selected_item)

    # Get the current values of the selected item
    values = event.widget.item(selected_item)['values']

    # Create an Entry widget for editing
    entry = ttk.Entry(event.widget)
    entry.insert(0, values[column_index])
    entry.column_index = column_index

    def save_edited_value(event):
        # Get the edited value from the Entry widget
        edited_value = event.widget.get()

        # Get the selected item (row)
        selected_item = event.widget.master

        # Get the column index of the selected cell
        column_index = event.widget.column_index

        # Update the value in the table
        selected_item.set(column_index, edited_value)

        # Destroy the Entry widget
        event.widget.destroy()

    # Save the edited value when Enter key is pressed or focus is lost
    entry.bind("<Return>", save_edited_value)
    entry.bind("<FocusOut>", save_edited_value)

    # Place the Entry widget in the selected cell
    event.widget.update_idletasks()  # Update the table layout before placing the Entry widget
    cell_bbox = event.widget.bbox(selected_item, column)  # Get the bounding box of the cell
    entry.place(x=cell_bbox[0], y=cell_bbox[1], width=cell_bbox[2] - cell_bbox[0], height=cell_bbox[3] - cell_bbox[1])

    # Set the focus to the Entry widget and select its contents
    entry.focus_set()
    entry.selection_range(0, tk.END)
```

I need the cells to editable inside my program.